# How to swap columns and rows of a multi-dimensional list in Python without using external libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that:

```py
>>> data

[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

When rows and columns are swapped:

```py
>>> data

[[1, 3, 5, 7],
 [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

How do I achieve the following without the use of external libraries such as pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6],
        [7, 8]]

print([*map(list, zip(*data))])
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```